# Reactive Extensions non-overlapping, serial GroupBy (or WindowUntilChange)

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I have tried to make a SerialGroupBy operator for Rx.Net. The point of the operator is to work like GroupBy, but each time a new group is created the former is completed. So there’s never more than one group open at a time.

My current "best" implementation is something like this:

```
public static IObservable<IGroupedObservable<TKey, TElement>> SerialGroupBy<TKey, TSource, TElement>(
    this IObservable<TSource> stream, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector) =>
    stream.Publish(shared => 
        shared.GroupByUntil(keySelector, elementSelector, group => 
            shared.DistinctUntilChanged(keySelector)));
```

And I hoped to get the group closing before the next group starts like tested here:

```
[Fact]
public void SerialGroupBy()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    var stream = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
        OnNext(201, "First group"),
        OnNext(202, "Second group"),
        OnNext(203, "Second group"));

    var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<string>();

    stream.SerialGroupBy(x => x.Length, x => x)
        .Select(x => x.Subscribe(observer))
        .Subscribe();

    scheduler.Start();

    observer.Messages.ShouldBeLike(
        OnNext(201, "First group"),
        OnCompleted<string>(202),
        OnNext(202, "Second group"),
        OnNext(203, "Second group"));
}
```

But the completion of the first groups comes too late, like:

```
OnNext(201, "First group"),
OnNext(202, "Second group"),
OnCompleted<string>(202),
OnNext(203, "Second group"));
```

I can understand why (the opening-observer is notified before the closing-observer as per the implementation of GroupByUntil), but how can I implement it so the groups are non-overlapping?

I have tried several different ways, but it always ends up with a variant of the same problem.

Comment: Besides for passing the test case, what is `SerialGroupBy` supposed to do?

Comment: @Shlomo Oh sorry, I guess I was too caught up in the details to remember that part :) It’s a GroupBy, but each time a new group is created the former is completed. So there’s never more than one group open at a time.

Comment: @Shlomo so it’s also kind of like non-overlapping windows that close when a selected value changes in the stream. Which have lead me to try a Scan based approach also, but without luck.

Comment: Why not do `.Merge().Subscribe(observer)` rather than `.Select(x => x.Subscribe()).Subscribe()`? Subscriptions within observables is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Enigmativity won't I miss the completions of the individual groups then? I couldn't figure out another way to test that the completion of the inner observable should come before the next opening, even though they arrive at the same time.

Comment: @asgerhallas - Sure, sorry, you're right. What you need is `.Select(x => x.Materialize()).Merge().Subscribe(observer)`, but then your observer has to be of type `Notification<string>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity ah, so that's a use case for Materialize. First time I get to use it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Enigmativity if it's of any interest, this is what I came up with in the end: https://gist.github.com/asgerhallas/b09ee2a8076d864b1227ed72bf68b79d. I'm not posting as an answer yet though, as it might have all sorts of uncovered edge cases still :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I came up with in the end:

```
public static class SerialGroupByOperator
{
    public static IObservable<IGroupedObservable<TKey, TElement>> SerialGroupBy<TKey, TSource, TElement>(
        this IObservable<TSource> stream, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector) =>
        Observable.Create<IGroupedObservable<TKey, TElement>>(observer => stream
            .Scan<TSource, GroupedObservable<TKey, TElement>>(null, (current, next) =>
            {
                var key = keySelector(next);

                if (current == null)
                {
                    var nextGroup = new GroupedObservable<TKey, TElement>(key);

                    observer.OnNext(nextGroup);
                    nextGroup.Group.OnNext(elementSelector(next));

                    return nextGroup;
                }

                if (!Equals(key, current.Key))
                {
                    current.Group.OnCompleted();

                    var nextGroup = new GroupedObservable<TKey, TElement>(key);

                    observer.OnNext(nextGroup);
                    nextGroup.Group.OnNext(elementSelector(next));

                    return nextGroup;
                }

                current.Group.OnNext(elementSelector(next));

                return current;
            })
            .LastOrDefaultAsync()
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .Subscribe(x => x.Group.OnCompleted(), observer.OnError, observer.OnCompleted));
}

internal class GroupedObservable<TKey, TElement> : IGroupedObservable<TKey, TElement>
{
    public GroupedObservable(TKey key)
    {
        Key = key;
        Group = new Subject<TElement>();
    }

    public TKey Key { get; }
    public ISubject<TElement> Group { get; }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<TElement> observer) => Group.Subscribe(observer);
}
```